# How to convert WMS layers to raster layers QGIS 1.8.0

Tags: wms, print-composer, raster-conversion, scale-bar

I need to export a series of maps for a report. The layers imported into QGIS are all WMS files provided by the GeoBC website. As I have now discovered, I cannot export these maps using the print composer because of the limitations of WMS. I also cannot add a scale bar to these maps as the WMS CRS is WGS 84 not UTM. If I understand the problem correctly, the solution would be to convert the WMS layers in to raster layers initially, and then to vector layers? Does this sound correct? If so, is there a tool to convert WMS to raster I can use as the first step?

Comment: GDAL should let you go WMS->Tiff http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a work around to making exportable maps using WMS layers. QGIS wont display the WMS layers in the print composer legend, so by creating phantom shapefile layers for each WMS layer and editing the properties so that the symbol in the legend for the PHANTOM layer matches that shown for the WMS layer, you can create a usable map.